# use a dictionary for word replacement with regex in python

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, f-string

I am trying to write a bit of code that will use regex to expand abbreviations in a text file to full words but not replace all instances of the abbreviation text.

I can’t figure out what goes in the pattern portion of the substitution function where I have placed ‘***’ below.  I can make the code work by hard coding in the abbreviation to substitute but I want to pass the key in the dictionary so that a single function can iterate through the dictionary and in the future I only need to update the dictionary. Can anybody clarify this for me?

```
import re

sample = 'premedicate with 0.3 mg/kg goofballs and 1.2 mg/kg happy dust with test string bmge or bmg or mgb'

fr_dict = {'kg': 'kilogram', 'mg': 'miligram', '/': ' per '}

for key in fr_dict:
    sample = re.sub(rf'{{***}}', lambda m: str(fr_dict[m.group(0)]), sample)
```

Comment: What does your expected output look like here?

Comment: “(\bkg\b|\bmg\|/)” might be a start - \b means “word boundary”. Then *eliminate* the loop.

Comment: `sample = re.sub(key, fr_dict[key], sample)`?

Comment: @ggorlen It should come out reading "premedicate with 0.3 miligram per kilogram goofballs and 1.2 miligram per kilogram happy dust with test string bmge or bmg or mgb"

Comment: @alec that replaces every instance not just the abbreviations making this string:

"premedicate with 0.3 miligram per kilogram goofballs and 1.2 miligram per kilogram happy dust with test string bmiligrame or bmiligram or miligramb"

Answer (score 2):

You can  iterate over dictionary, replacing key found in string with value:

```
import re

sample = 'premedicate with 0.3 mg/kg goofballs and 1.2 mg/kg happy dust with test string bmge or bmg or mgb'

fr_dict = {'kg': 'kilogram', 'mg': 'miligram', '/': ' per '}

for key, value in fr_dict.items():
    sample = re.sub(rf'\b{key}\b', value, sample)

print(sample)
# premedicate with 0.3 miligram per kilogram goofballs and 1.2 miligram per kilogram happy dust with test string bmge or bmg or mgb
```

Note that the word boundary helps us to replace only full words that match.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit simpler than you may think. If you use `.items()` on the replacements dict, you have access to both the key and replacement value in your loop.

Another way to do it is to join the keys into an alternation and substitute using the lambda to look up the correct swap pair:

```
pattern = "|".join(rf"\b{x}\b" for x in swaps.keys())
re.sub(pattern, lambda x: swaps[x.group()], sample)
```

Usage:

```
>>> import re
>>> sample = 'premedicate with 0.3 mg/kg goofballs and 1.2 mg/kg happy dust with test string bmge or bmg or mgb'
>>> swaps = {'kg': 'kilogram', 'mg': 'miligram', '/': ' per '}
>>> pattern = "|".join(rf"\b{x}\b" for x in swaps.keys())
>>> re.sub(pattern, lambda x: swaps[x.group()], sample)
'premedicate with 0.3 miligram per kilogram goofballs and 1.2 miligram per kilogram happy dust with test string bmge or bmg or mgb'
```

Comment: You could have done similar way using `.items()` as well.

Comment: Yes, that was my original answer and I explain how to do it at the top of the post. I think I smushed it in the edit history.

Comment: Thank you both. I've been working on this for too long and you've given me several good solutions.